# OCTAVE cells and strings

Tags: string, matrix, octave, cells

What is the opposite function of `cellstr`?

explanation: first I have:

`d=["aa";"bb";"cc";"dd"];`

then I do:

`d=cellstr(d);`

but then I want to have `d` back in shape like it was on the begining (that is matrix).

How do I do that?/What function should I use?
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job: d=char(d(:,1));